# How to calculate lexical density of every sentence of a tagged file?

Tags: python, lexical-analysis, part-of-speech

I have a [file tagged by part-of-speech](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CzZeAZPym4Vaed2i8xSENUe_OPlO8eN6/view?usp=sharing) containing 260 sentences. I want to calculate the lexical density (sum of content words - nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs - divided by the total sum of words) sentence by sentence of this tagged file.

first I need to split the text into sentences and after that iterate in each sentence searching for the tags and counting them. I was only able so far to split the text into sentences, but I don't know how to look for the correct tags (VERB, NOUN, ADJ, ADV) in each sentence and count them to divide by the total number of words in the sentence. Can anyone help me with this task? The code I tried so far is below.

```
    def sent_ld():

        while True:
            try:
                file_to_open =Path(input("\nYOU SELECTED OPTION 8: CALCULATE SENTENCE 
LENGTH. 
    Please, insert your file path: "))
                with open(file_to_open,'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    sentences = f.read()
                    break   
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("\nFile not found. Better try again")
            except IsADirectoryError:
                print("\nIncorrect Directory path.Try again")



        units=sentences.split('<<SPACE>>')



   tags=[ 'ADJ','ADP','NOUN','ADV','AUX','CONJ','CCONJ','DET','INTJ','NOUN','NUM','PART','PRON','PROPN','PUNCT','SCONJ','SYM','VERB','X','SPACE']

        pat=re.compile('[A-Z][A-Z]+')

        for u in units:
            m=re.findall(pat, u)



        summ=[]
        remaining=[]
        space=[]
        punct=[]
        num=[]
        propn=[]

        d1=defaultdict(int)

        for i in m:
            if i in tags:
                d1[i]+=1


        sent_number=1


        for y in d1:
            if y =='ADV':
                soma.append(d1[y])
            elif y == 'NOUN':
                soma.append(d1[y])

            elif y == 'ADJ':
                soma.append(d1[y])
            elif y == 'VERB':
                soma.append(d1[y])
            elif y == 'PROPN':
                soma.append(d1[y])
            elif y == 'SYM':
                soma.append(d1[y])
            elif y == 'SPACE':
                space.append(d1[y])
            elif y == 'PUNCT':
                punct.append(d1[y])
            elif y == 'NUM':
                num.append(d1[y])      
            else:
                resto.append(d1[y])
            print('Sentence',sent_number, 'lexical density is: ', sum(summ)/sum(remaining))
            sent_number+=1
    sent_ld()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly. But based on the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CzZeAZPym4Vaed2i8xSENUe_OPlO8eN6/view) that you shared, and given the fact that you are able capture the sentences in the variable `units`, instead of using a `defaultdict` you could in turn split the `units` into `lines`. It seems that if you split `lines` again using space, you will get a list of length 3, per line.

The second item in these lists is the tag you are looking for. Since, you consider particular tags in the lexical count, you could create a local variable `lexical_count` within the second loop and set it to 0. Everytime one of the lexical tags is encountered the value of this variable is incremented by 1.

```py
for sentence_num, unit in enumerate(units, 1):
    lines = unit.split('\n')
    total_count = len(lines)
    lexical_count = 0
    for line in lines:
        token, tag, _ = line.split()
        if tag in {'ADV', 'NOUN', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'PROPN', 'SYM'}:
            lexical_count += 1
    density = lexical_count / total_count
    print(f'Sentence {sentence_num}, Lexical Density is: {density}')
```

Comment: when I run this code capturing the sentences in the variable units I get the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nataliaresende/Desktop/TGITT_per_files_cleaned/Lexical_density_sentence_by_sentence.py", line 33, in <module>
    token, tag, _ = lines.split()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split